# Grub2 efi multiboot

Tags: usb, настройка

Пытаюсь сделать мультизагрузочную флэшку на основе grub2-efi.

1. Записал на флэшку grub pc-efi.
2. Залил образы (распакованные) Винды, все грузит, все нормально
3. Залил образ Debian и тут первый затык
4. Залил файлы наподобие Victoria, mhdd, memtest и т.д. и тут второй затык
5. Залил программу rEFInd, грузит, отрабатывает, но неправильно считает конфиги. Это третий затык

Насчет затыков

1. При попытке установки Debian Jessie 8.2 из iso-файла, linux начинает отрабатывать, но слетает на поиске образа диска.

   ```
   menuentry "Debian 8.2 Jessie" {
   echo "Настройка окружения"
   set isofile="/boot/tools/debian-live-8.2.iso"
   loopback loop $isofile
   echo "Загрузка ядра Linux"
   linux (loop)/install/gtk/vmlinuz boot=live noprompt iso-scan/filename=$isofile vga=normal --
   echo "Монтирование файловой системы"
   initrd (loop)/install/gtk/initrd.img
   }
   ```
2. При попытке загрузить MHDD - зависает на последнем этапе

   ```
   echo "Поиск ядра Memdisk"
   search -f /boot/tools/memdisk -s root
   echo "Загрузка ядра Memdisk"
   linux16 /boot/tools/memdisk 
   echo "Загрузка программы MHDD"
   initrd16 /boot/tools/mhdd32.iso
   ```
3. Насчет rEFInd - в принципе фигня, но хотелось бы, чтобы все меня слушалось.
4. есть еще один момент - не могу загрузить Alkid LiveCD

   ```
   echo "Подключение модулей"
   insmod ntldr
   echo "Поиск файла загрузки"
   search -f /alkid/i386/setupldr.bin -s root
   echo "Загрузка лайв диска"
   ntldr /alkid/i386/setupldr.bin
   boot
   ```

Как с помощью GRUB2 загрузить Kaspersky Rescue Disk?

```
set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode 
insmod gzio 
insmod part_msdos 
insmod ext2 
insmod fat 
insmod ntfs 
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8614-5FEE 
linux /boot/rescue 
subdir=/
root=/dev/ram0 
vga=791 
init=/linuxrc 
looptype=squashfs 
loop=/image.squashfs 
nodevfs kav_lang=en udev aufs quiet noresume doscsi 
kav_lang=ru 
cdroot=/dev/sd[a-z][0-9] 
initrd /boot/rescue.igz`
```

Answer (score 1):

По поводу пункта №1 : пример работающего загрузчика:

```
menuentry 'ubuntu 16.04 betta amd64' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
insmod fat
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 13166a2a-3a97-4e8c-8bbc-ab052d7217f0
loopback loop /xenial-desktop-amd64.iso
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/xenial-desktop-amd64.iso noeject noprompt --
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

здесь в `search` указывается UUID диска (в моем случае - это второй раздел на Flash-накопителе).